# Hiding rows with class "hidden" after change the checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using [jQuery datatables](https://datatables.net).  I'd like to hide all rows with `class="hidden"`.

This code:

```
var table = $('#table1').DataTable();
table.rows('.hidden').hide();
```

It's not working (rows are not hidden), and I see this text in console:

> table.rows(...).hide is not a function

How can I use `class="hidden"` to hide all rows?

---

HTML code:

```
<tr class="">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>17</td>
</tr>

<tr class="hidden">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>DEF</td>
    <td>22</td>
</tr>

<tr class="">
    <td>3</td>
    <td>GHI</td>
    <td>55</td>
</tr>

<tr class="hidden">
    <td>4</td>
    <td>JKL</td>
    <td>11</td>
</tr>
<input id="hideRows" name="hideRows" type="checkbox">
```

JS code:

```
$('#table1').DataTable();

$('#hideRows').change(function() 
{
    var table = $('#table1').DataTable();
    $('tr.hidden').hide();
    $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
        if ($(oSettings.nTable).hasClass('hidden')) {
            return aData[16] == '' || $('#hideRows').is(':checked');
        } else return true;
    });
    table.draw();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solutions assume that the rows have already been marked with the `hidden` class.

To use DataTable filtering to hide the rows, implement a filter function, like this:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
   function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
      return $(table.row(dataIndex).node()).hasClass('hidden');
   }
);
```

While it's not recommended, you *can* use jQuery to hide the rows, but there are *gotchas*.  (There are valid reasons that you may need to do this, but they will not be covered here.)  Simply query the `hidden` class of the HTML `tr` elements using a regular jQuery selector, and then apply [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), like this:

```
$('tr.hidden').hide();
```

If you use non-filter functions to hide the rows (either using the jQuery method above, or with CSS styling on the `hidden` class), there may be side effects.  See [jQuery DataTable - Hide rows the intended way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347179/jquery-datatable-hide-rows-the-intended-way) for additional information.  If you display / filtering issues, you'll have to let DataTables know which rows have already been hidden:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(function(oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
    if ($(oSettings.nTable).hasClass('hidden')) {
        return aData[16] == '' || $('#chkShowExcluded').is(':checked');
    } else return true;
});
```

Note that after using any of these methods, you may have to force a redraw after applying the `hidden` classes to the table rows, like this:

```
table.draw();
```

Comment: Hi Michael,
Thanks for your answer.
I've been trying to use your code, rows has been removed,but I still see old number of entries, even though table has been updated. 
Can you check my code ? ->
http://wklej.org/id/2638128/

Comment: It is very hard to read code included in a comment.  Can you update your question with the information?  If you click the `edit` link below the question, you can copy the code in there.  It looks like you may have to include more code, as well, such as the code that adds the `hidden` class.

Comment: OK, I updated my first comment and i added link to code :-)

Comment: OK, for future reference, when someone on StackOverflow says "Question", they mean the original question that was asked, all the way at the top of the page.  What you edited was a *comment* that happened to ask a follow-up question, but would still be called a *comment*.  What I need to see is how the `hidden` class gets added to the rows and how the `#hideRows` id is used with the table.  These are the keys to figuring out why the code isn't working, but they're only referenced here, so I can't tell how they were established.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve) to understand how to provide the right level of information to debug an issue.

Comment: OK ,thanks for information , i will remember it :-)
Question updated, hidden class is in rows from beginning

Comment: @Star089 I have created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mgaskill/9Lcgvyet/) for you based on your example code.  Note that I've factored out the jQuery selectors to be cached once, and I've also moved the filter function outside the `change` handler, since it only needs to be installed one time.

Comment: Thank you very much, now everything is ok :-) I wish you have a nice evening!

Comment: Good deal!  You have a great evening, as well.  :D

Comment: Yes, You've been a great help! Now I can happily watch game on EURO 2016 :D