# Hide DataTable Row During Initial Draw, But Searchable

Tags: datatables

Looking for help to hide a row during initial draw, but having the filtering/sorting still work. I've searched all day without making any headway. I'm using server-side and the DataTable API, like so:

```
  uTable = $('#datatables-users').DataTable({
      processing: true,
      serverSide: true,
      ajax: {
        url: '<?php echo url('users/datatable'); ?>',
        type: "POST",
      },
      columns: [ {"visible":false}, null, null, null, null, null, null} ]
    });
  });
```

My first column is hidden and the item I would like to filter on. It's currently either a "1" or "0" where I would like initial state to hide "1" column values.

I've tried using filters such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17347493/888462) but assume that will not work with server-side execution.

Would appreciate any direction or thoughts. Thank you.

Comment: Yep, you would need to do that on server. When serverSide is enabled, it's upto the server script to filter out any rows.

Comment: Thanks @colin0117. For anyone else that comes across this, I did some basic logic on `$_POST['search]` and passed it to the server.